# On view add line breaks to text file

Tags: linux, shell, cgi

I wonder if anyone can help me with this little problem.  I want to view a text file through a web page.  However, the text file has no line breaks or formatting.

Is there any way to temporarily add line breaks while viewing?

I'd like to achieve this through shell scripting.

Sample text file:

```
    This is a sample text file.

    Same concept.

    Text has no format. 100 of lines...
```

Maybe not the best solution... but I used the following method to get this working:

**Solution:**

```
    FILE=$rpt

    while read LINE; do
        echo "$LINE<br>"
    done < "$FILE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE=$1
TEMP=$(mktemp /tmp/XXXXXXXX.html)
BROWSER=firefox

{
    echo "<html><head></head><body><div>"
    while read LINE; do
        echo "$LINE<br>"
    done
    echo "</div></body></html>"
} < "$FILE" > "$TEMP"

"$BROWSER" "$TEMP"
# sleep 5  ## If your browser launches in the background. Firefox doesn't.
rm -f "$TEMP"
```

Run it as `sh script.sh /path/to/file.txt`.

Comment: I used your while loop idea in my solution.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

When files are sent by your web server, they are sent with a "content type" that corresponds to the type of file. Your web server sounds like it is probably sending as type `text/html`, and therefore the browser will expect the file to be HTML formatted.

See if you can instruct your web server to send your file as `text/plain`, which may be as simple as renaming the file to have a `.txt` extension.